# Removing an Object from its holder

Tags: circular-dependency

Let's assume I have three classes, as follwing:

```
class A {
  Array<B> bs;
  createB() { b = new B(); this.bs.insert(b); return b; }
}

class B {
  Array<C> cs;
  createC() { c = new C(); this.cs.insert(c); return c; }
}

class C {
  delete() { ... }
}
```

A holds Bs, and B holds Cs. C has a delete method on which for a given C, c, I want to delete its B from the A that eventually holds c.

A simple way of doing it is to hold a backward-reference to the holder object. This way, C's delete method can be written as:

```
delete() { this.b.a.bs.remove(this.b); }
```

But I'm ending up with a circular dependency in which each class is aware of the others. I want any lower class to not be aware of its holder class.

Any ideas on how to solve this more elegantly? I would also appreciate a solution that can be applied on a hierarchy that is larger that only three classes.

Edit:
I might have not been clear enough, but my point is that C class is an "action receiver", like a button on the screen with many options to click on. A and B are more of a logical elements that has no screen representation but group data together.

Let's assume B has a shape attribute, and C has a color attribute.

I want to be able to click on C and supply these methods (just some made-up examples):

```
Delete() { go to B, and delete this C from it array }
PaintAllRed() { go to B, for each C set color red }
ShapeSquare() { go to B, go to it's A, for each B of A set shape square }
```

I basically want to know how can C inform B (and A) that an action was made by the user.

Comment: Why on Earth would you want that? If `B` creates a new `C` object and stores it, then `B` should also be responsible for deleting it. Everything else is just confusing ownership and *will* eventually come crashing down on your head.

Comment: You could set up an event. For example, when class B adds a C to its array, it could also subscribe to its events. Then when the C deletes itself, it can raise the event, and B would know to remove that particular C from its array. Similarly, A could subscribe to B's events, resulting in a cascading delete.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, the best approach to the hierarchy problem is to ensure a node is never aware of its parents, as you alluded to. I believe that's the industry standard, so the situation you're encountering where a child needs to invoke behavior on a parent it shouldn't know about is pretty common (UI composition is somewhere this crops up a lot). There are three approaches I can think of:

- Have the parent pass access to the removal *behavior* to the child (pass the child a function it can call to remove itself). This is good in JavaScript and Python, but in languages where functions aren't easily treated as variables doing this sucks.
- Have the parent be responsible for deleting it's children. So to delete a `C` you'd call a `removeC` method of it's parent `B`.
- Deal with having the back-references. The way this data structure is being propagated through your application may dictate that you have to do it this way without major refactoring.